# Adding letsencrypt cert to nodejs http server?

Tags: node.js, ssl, lets-encrypt

Lets say I have a simple nodejs http server as stated below and also  [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificates ready in `/etc/letsencrypt`. How do I go about changing to https and adding the certificates?

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World!');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function () {
   console.log('Started!');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `https` module. Here is an example of how you can configure your server:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

function letsencryptOptions(domain) {
    const path = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/';
    return {
        key: fs.readFileSync(path + domain + '/privkey.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path + domain + '/cert.pem'),
        ca: fs.readFileSync(path + domain + '/chain.pem')
    };
}

const options = letsencryptOptions('example.com');
https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

Comment: There is no key.pem and no cert.pem files... There are some pem files in other folders though.

Comment: @vidstige, what is the file for certificate?

Comment: @vidstige, then you probably have not used `letsencrypt` correctly to generate the certificate. [check this](https://gist.github.com/davestevens/c9e437afbb41c1d5c3ab)

Comment: Thanks, the code in the link works. Can you update your answer?